# Вывод полей в JSF

Tags: java, jsf, java-ee, primefaces

Вопрос в следующем: при использовании любого компонента ввода, возьмем, к примеру, h:inputText, если определить связанную с ним переменную как числовую - int или double, то при загрузке страницы в этом поле уже будет введено значение 0 или 0.0. Если поставить тип данных String, то все в порядке, поле пустое.

Можно ли как-нибудь избавиться от этих нулей? Смысл даже не в том, чтобы эти значения убирались автоматически при вводе данных, а чтобы их изначально там не было.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Под рукой сейчас нет проекта на JSF, попробуйте использовать Integer и Double

Comment: Спасибо! И ведь точно, дело в типах данных! Простые типы не получали значение null и выводили 0.

Answer (score 0):

Не используйте в полях ввода примитивные типы данных, которые инициализируются со значением 0 ( `int`, `long`, `float`, `double`, `char`) .

Используйте для этого классы `Integer`, `Long`, `Float`, `Double`, `String`, которые по умолчанию инициализируются со значением `null`.

> JSF не отображает `null` - объекты.